# Extend concept of weak derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $f \in H^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then we have for $|\alpha| \le m$ that

$$\langle \partial^{\alpha}f, \phi  \rangle = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \langle f , \partial^{\alpha} \phi \rangle$$ 
for all test functions $\phi$,

now let's take a sequence of $C^{\infty}_C$ cut-off functions $\psi_n$ such that $\psi_n \rightarrow 1$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\partial^{\alpha} \psi_n  \rightarrow  0$ for any $|\alpha| \le m$, then we have for any $g \in H^m(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap C^{\infty}$

$\langle \partial^{\alpha}f,\psi_n g\rangle  = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \langle f, \partial^{\alpha} (\psi_n g) \rangle  = \sum_{\beta \le \alpha} \binom{ \alpha}{\beta}\langle f, \partial^{\beta} \psi_n \partial^{\alpha-\beta}g\rangle$. Now,if I see this correctly, then the dominated convergence theorem implies (cause all derivatives of $\psi_n$ go to zero) that

$$\langle \partial^{\alpha}f,g \rangle  = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \langle f, \partial^{\alpha} g\rangle. $$

Now my question is: This is REALLY strange, cause this would imply that instead of testing with $C^{\infty}_C$ functions, if something is weakly differentiable, I could also use the much larger class of $C^{\infty} \cap H^m$ functions. Can this be correct?

So my question is: Is this proof alright?

Comment: Why would that be strange? Most of the time, you want the set of test functions to be as small as possible (while having the properties you want it to have), not large.

Comment: well, because it is a so large class of functions, is my proof correct then?

Comment: Seems okay to me, but my pde are a bit rusty, so I might be overlooking something.

Comment: Actually this is not so strange, as $C^\infty_C$ is dense in $H^m$.

Comment: $C_c^\infty$ is dense...so you could actually test against $H^m$...

Comment: okay, I believe you now, but just for completeness: My proof is also alright?

Comment: Your proof is only right if you assume more on the functions $\psi_n$, so that applying dominated convergence is indeed justified. As it stands, it is not clear that there is a dominating function.

Comment: @PhoemueX okay, they should be bounded (and their derivatives) by 1.